# In Vaadin 7, pass data/arguments to new UI instance of BrowserWindowOpener?

Tags: java, window, vaadin, vaadin7

I am successfully opening new browser windows with [BrowserWindowOpener](https://vaadin.com/api/7.0.3/com/vaadin/server/BrowserWindowOpener.html).

Question: How do I pass some information to the newly instantiated UI subclass?

The syntax requires that I specify a class to be instantiated. How do I communicate with that future instance?

```
BrowserWindowOpener bookOpener = new BrowserWindowOpener( BookUI.class );
```

For example, let's say my app opens a window listing word definitions for words starting with a particular letter of the alphabet (A-Z). How do I tell the newly opening UI that it should show the "A" words, the "B" words, or the "V" words?

I noticed the [BrowserWindowOpenerState](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/shared/ui/BrowserWindowOpenerState.html) class, but its use is not documented.

Comment: One workaround I found is to (1) Add member fields to my UI subclass, (2) Create a further subclass that hard-codes values into those member fields. In example above, this would mean creating 26 subclasses: "BookUI_A", "BookUI_B", "BookUI_C", and so on. Less than elegant.

Answer (score 4):

I have not tried this, but a quick look at the javadoc suggests that by  using [BrowserWindowOpener#setParameter](https://vaadin.com/api/7.0.3/com/vaadin/server/BrowserWindowOpener.html#setParameter%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) or [BrowserWindowOpener#setUriFragment](https://vaadin.com/api/7.0.3/com/vaadin/server/BrowserWindowOpener.html#setUriFragment%28java.lang.String%29) you can pass parameters into the UI.

E.g.

```
BrowserWindowOpener bookOpener = new BrowserWindowOpener( BookUI.class );
bookOpener.setParameter("startLetter", "A");

...

class BookUI {
  protected abstract void init(VaadinRequest request){
    String startLetter = request.getParameter("startLetter");
    // Etc
  }
}
```